# Show that the Klein bottle with a deleted closed disk $K\setminus D$ is not a retract of $K$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Show that the Klein bottle $K$ with a deleted closed disk $K\setminus D$ is not a retract of $K$.

I tried drawing a picture of the Klein bottle as a simplical complex and deleting a disk from the picture, but I don't think I deleted the disk right.

Suppose there was a retraction $r:K\longrightarrow K\setminus D$. We have a theorem that says if a space $X$ retracts onto a subspace $A$, then the homomorphism $i_{*}:\pi _1(A)\longrightarrow\pi _1(X)$ is an injection. So, if we had a retraction it would induce an injection $i_{*}:\pi _1(K\setminus D)\longrightarrow\pi _1(K)$ which we can rewrite as:  $<a,b|ab =b^{-1} a>\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} *\mathbb{Z}$.

Any suggestions or alternative ways to prove this?

Comment: Hint: $K\setminus D$ deformation retracts onto $S^1\vee S^1$.

Comment: For the above hint; consider the planar representation of the klein bottle, delete a small disk from the center and see what the boundary retracts to.

Comment: So, $r_{*}: <a,b|ab=b^{-1}a>\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z} *\mathbb{Z}$ is onto

Comment: I'm not good when it comes to free products.  Where does the contradiction come from?

Comment: I think I've figured it out.  I have that $i_{*} :\pi _1(K\setminus D)\longrightarrow \pi _1(K)$ can be rewritten as $<a,b|ab =b^{-1} a>\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} *\mathbb{Z}$ or $<\mathbb{Z} *\mathbb{Z} |a^2 =b^2>\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} *\mathbb{Z}$.  By the latter, we would have elements in $\mathbb{Z} *\mathbb{Z}$ not mapped to because of the conditions set on the domain. Is that correct?

Comment: It is easy to see that the induced map of the inclusion of a retract on the fundamental group has to be injective. But now if you look at the fundamental group of $K \setminus D$ you get that the map is not injective, because its exactly dividing out the relation in the fundamental group of the Klein Bottle, which gives you the desired contradiction.

Comment: consider functor $H_2(-,\mathbb Z_2)$

Comment: @ThorbenKastenholz thank you for correcting me.  I don't know why I was thinking surjection, instead of injection.  That's the price of working late without sleep.  Also, could you explain to me what you mean by "dividing out the relation in the fundamental group of the Klein Bottle"

Comment: I don't understand this mapping and where the contradiction is coming from.

Comment: Just compare the fundamental group of the klein bottle with the fundamental group of its $1$-Skeleton. These are the two spaces in question here.

Comment: I see right now, that since you're asking for deleting the closed disc it is even easier. It is an easy exercise to show that in Hausdorff spaces retracts have to be closed, but the complement of a closed disc is not closed.

Comment: I like the latter argument the best! Thanks for all your help.